# Очищенный активированный уголь (запятые)

Tags: пунктуация, грамматика

Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужны ли запятые в словосочетании "очищенный активированный уголь"?
Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А разве есть неочищенный? Активация - не очищение.

«Активация» активированного угля, благодаря которой он получил свое название, состоит в том, что в процессе термической обработки сырья на высоких температурах не происходит его контакта с огнем. Сырье изолируется непосредственно от пламени либо используются электрические методы нагрева.
Источник: https://hobbymaniya.ru/faq/iz-chego-delayut-aktivirovannyy-ugol-v-tabletkah/

Если такое сочетание возможно, то это в любом случае неоднородные определения, запятой нет.

Comment: Спасибо. Неоднородные, значит, все-таки.